# redirect $_GET['id'] if not set

Tags: php, pdo

I am running into this odd situation about regex. I wanna check first if ID is set, if not then redirect to `index.php`

THIS IS **INDEX.PHP**

```
$title = "This is a title";
$id = "5";
$queryc = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = :id");
$queryc->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$queryc->execute();

/*** fetch the results ***/
$resultc = $queryc->fetchAll();
$count = count($resultc);
if ($count > 0) 
{
foreach($resultc as $rowc)

    {
    $cat_name = htmlentities($rowc['cat_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
    $cat_name = stripslashes($cat_name);

    }
 }else {
 //redirect is a function 
 redirect("index.php");
 }
 echo "  
 <td width='57%' height='126' class='bord'  ><a href='$cat_name-$id.htm'  

 class='title_style'>" . $title . "</a><br>";
```

`$cat_name` could have two words separated with space or it could have accented chars too except some chars.  For that I used **.htaccess**

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^([^!@#$%^&*(){}]+)-(\d+)\.htm$   file.php?id=$2 [L]
```

In **file.php** where the result shows I wanted to make sure that $id is set

```
if( isset($_GET['id']) )
{

$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

    if( $id == 0 )
    {
        redirect("index.php");
        exit;   
    }

}   
else
{
redirect("index.php");
    exit;
}
```

In the browser it will look like this: 
**mydomain.com/auto auction-5.htm**

**My problem is:**
`$cat_name = auto auction;` (notice the space) it doesn't work, but if `$cat_name = autoauction;` with no space it works.

How do I get it to work when spaces are there?

Comment: What do you mean by "not set"? do you mean that the string passed would be "category name-" or "category name-0" ?

Why do you need to use PHP? can't you just use the regex that you are already using in your .htaccess file to determine if that digit is there?

Comment: lets say $id = 5,the url would be mydomain.com/auto auction-5.htm and if I run this mydomain.com/auto auction-2045.htm I want it to redirect to index.php since 2045 doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has special char(space), witch will cause the browser to encode your query first then send it. To get over this situation, you have first to decode it with [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).